# make sitemap page for many pages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap

I just noticed that Google didn't crawl quite a lot of my web pages. When I searched for that reason, I thought sitemap could be a reason for some part of that missing crawling because I had no sitemap or robots.txt kind of thing.

I have a very simple structured website with index, QnA, login(no user's page yet) and search page. But Search page can result in many restaurants' pages, which are upto almost 160,000 like **example.com/restaurants/1000001** to **example.com/restaurants/1160000**.

I just learned some concepts about sitemap and I think dynamic sitemap examples are quite a lot in google. But I saw that over 50,000 pages require some more sitemaps [google sitemap help page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=6080646&rd=1).

My website has very very simple structure but would it make some burden for my server?(is it necessary?) And I have no clear standard to split those 160,000 pages, then what can be a good standard to split them for googlebot?

Any tips would be a huge help for me. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077266/google-sitemap-files-for-rails-projects for some tips.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy, Thanks for your comment! I already saw that question but I wanted to know the possibility of some problems because I have many web pages.